# Save variable value while navigation in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewdata, tempdata, state-management

I am having one page **ABC.cshtml**. In the page I have written code for multiple modal popup with "**Back**" and "**Next**" buttons. when I click on buttons it navigates from one modal to another.

I am having "**Id**" which I need to persist when I navigate from one modal to another but "Id" became null.

I have used **Tempdata/Viewdata/Viewbag/Hidden field** to persist data but no use. I cant use session to save state here. Is there any other way to do this?

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Just asking, what's wrong with using Session?

Comment: Session State will be blocked if concurrent async ajax requests are executed, it will affect performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cache

Add `System.Runtime.Caching`

[image]

```
//Add cache named Key1. It will expire in 10 minute
CacheWrapper.Add("Key1", new List<int>(), 10);

//Get the cache
var result = CacheWrapper.Get<List<int>>("Key1");

//Delete the cache
CacheWrapper.Delete("Key1");
```

Create wrapper class like this

```
public class CacheWrapper
{
    private static ObjectCache cache = null;

    public static ObjectCache Cache
    {
        get
        {
            if (cache == null)
            {
                cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            }
            return cache;
        }
    }

    public static void Add(string key, object data, double expireInMinute)
    {
        Delete(key);
        Cache.Add(key, data, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireInMinute));
    }

    public static object Get(string key)
    {
        if (!Cache.Contains(key))
            return null;
        return Cache[key];
    }

    public static void Delete(string key)
    {
        if (Cache.Contains(key))
        {
            Cache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cache is application wide, it is shared across all sessions and this is one of the main difference between session and cache. I am not sure this will solve the original question when there are multiple sessions of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hidden Field

```
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English">
```

In asp.Net:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="Language" runat="server" value="English"/>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention in the question but I have tried hidden fields as well